# Get UniqueId from listitem with Javascript/Ecmascript (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, javascript, list-item, guid, unique

Is it possible to get the **Unique Id** from a listitem in a custom SharePoint 2010 list?
I've added a custom ribbon action so far where I can get the id, but that's an integer (0,1,2,3,...) I need the unique Guid of that listitem.

Anyone knows if this is possible and if so, how can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: why not integet Id so you can use GetItemById method?

Comment: The problem with this is that the listitems change a lot. If someone gets the id, the listitem can allready be gone. That's why I use the UniqueId, so I won't get any mistakes. And I can use the GetItemByUniqueId() method to get it also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a script that gets the UniqueId of a list item:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
    {           
      ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
        function()
        {

          var itemId = ....; // change to the real id
          var listTitle = .... // the list title

          var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
          var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

          var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
          ctx.load(item);


          ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                  function ()
                  {                    
                     alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + item.get_item('UniqueId'));
                  },

                  function(sender, args)
                  {
                          alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
                  });
        }, "sp.js");
    });
</script>
```

Hint: If your ribbon action is used in a list view, then you could use the following to get the current list:

```
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
```